# window.localStorage.setItem not working on mobile phone

Tags: android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, local-storage

I am working on HTML5 mobile app using jQuery mobile.

This is my code:

```
$(document).on("click","#send_mobile_number",function(){

    var mobile = $('#mobile_number').val();
    var user_id = sessionStorage.getItem("user_id");


    $('.ui-loader').show();

    $.ajax({
        url: BASE_URL+'users/send_sms_code.php',
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'json',
        data: "user_id="+user_id+"&mobile="+mobile+"&type=1",
        async:false,
        success: function (response) {
            var data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            $('.ui-loader').hide();

            if(data.status == 'Fail') {
                $('.very_mob_no_message').html('Sorry some error occurred,try again.');
            }else{                   
                $('#close_mob_popup').trigger('click');

                setTimeout(function()
                {
                    $('.click_mobile_verify').trigger('click');
                }, 500);

                $('#send_mobile_verify_span').hide();
                $('#after_mobile_send_span').show();

                $('#moble_number_div').hide();
                $('#user_code_div').show();

                $('#user_code').val(data.sms_code);

                //alert(window.localStorage.getItem('mobile'));

                //sessionStorage.setItem("mobile",mobile);
                window.localStorage.setItem("mobile",mobile); // IT IS NOT WORKING


                $('.very_mobile_message').html('Enter code which is <br/> sent to your mobile number.');

            }


        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            //alert(jqXHR.status);
        }
    });  

});
```

I want to store mobile number in session using `window.localStorage.setItem("mobile",mobile);`. It is working when I run on my browser but when I runt on mobile phone as APP it stop working. Why this happening. I am checking android phone.

Comment: something's wrong with `if(data.status == 'Fail')` inside a `success` function... By definition, it won't trigger the success function if it fails.

Comment: It enter into success loop but localstorage not working

Comment: Enough with "localStorage is not working", already. localStorage is a browser feature, it works. The alert test failed (other comments), so the alert is not reached, so the problem is elsewhere. Watch your console for errors, try to console.log stuff, like `console.log(response)` or `console.log(data)`, and see if they're reached, and what they output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally found the solution, I need to set `webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);` on android code and after this localstorage is working perfectlly.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `localStorage.mobile = "mobile"`. It's as simple as that. localStorage is a global object and can be accessed and manipulated as any other object. The only difference with regular objects is that it can store only strings.

You can then retrieve your value using `alert( localStorage.mobile ); // will alert "mobile"`

Comment: what is the value and key in this ?

Comment: Like any object : `object.key = value`. Or `object['key'] = value`.

Comment: Okay, try this code : `localStorage.mobile = "mobile" ; alert(localStorage.mobile)`. What does it alert?

Comment: I tried that too but it does not alert anything. It stop working

Comment: So the problem is not the localStorage... You made a wrong diagnosis. Try setting up an `.error()` statement instead of writing `if(data.status == 'Fail')` inside a `success` function. Watch your console for errors. Any errors displayed in it?

Comment: I am checking on mobile phone...on browser it is working perfectly

Comment: Are you converting HTML5 to app with Phonegap or something?

Comment: localStorage is fully supported by Phonegap. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_localstorage_localstorage.md.html This reinforces the "the error is elsewhere" theory. What did the different `console.log` output?

Comment: I have set webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true); on android code then my code worked perfectlly. Anyways thanks for your help :)